# Creating 2 different entities using one controller.create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to create a new entity `B` whenever I create an entity `A`. To do this I tried adding a call to `B.create` inside the `A.create` method in `a_controller`. This however gives an error:

```
Missing template a/create
```

So my question is: how do I create an entity `B` from the `A.create` controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
def create
  @A = A.new(params[:a])
  @B = B.new(params[:b])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @A.save && @B.save
      format.html { redirect_to @A, :notice => 'A was successfully created.' }        
    else
      # render new with validation errors
      format.html { render :action => "new" }        
    end
  end
end
```

but if your objects are 'related', i.e. has_many or belongs_to then you might want something like

```
# project has_many tasks
def create
  @project = Project.new(params[:project])
  @project.tasks.new(params[:task])
  if @project.save # this should save both objects and in the same transaction
    ....
end
```

and third option is to use accepts_nested_attributes_for - read more here: http://currentricity.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/the-definitive-guide-to-accepts_nested_attributes_for-a-model-in-rails-3/